# Trying to display webcam footage on webpage from OpenCV (Django) while using docker

Tags: python, django, docker, opencv

I am trying to create a facial recognition attendance system - My project framework is DJango and I have deployed it on docker, however I am running into issues trying to access the webcam through docker.

This is my code:

views.py:

```
class mycamera(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.frames = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

def __del__(self):
    self.frames.release()

def get_jpg_frame(self):
    is_captured, frame = self.frames.read()
    retval, jframe = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    return jframe.tobytes()

def livefeed():
    camera_object = mycamera()
    while True:
        jframe_bytes = camera_object.get_jpg_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + jframe_bytes + b'\r\n\r\n')


@condition(etag_func=None)
def display_livefeed(self):
     return StreamingHttpResponse(
            livefeed(),
            content_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame'
        )
```

urls.py:

```
from users import views as user_views
    path('vidstream/', user_views.display_livefeed, name='vidStream')
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"


services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    devices:
      - /dev/video0:/dev/video0
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=XXXX
      - POSTGRES_USER=XXXX
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=XXXX
    container_name: postgresdb
```

Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -U pip wheel cmake
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

Error code when access 0.0.0.0:8000/vidstream/:

```
web_1       | [04/Jan/2022 17:47:16] "GET /vidstream/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
web_1       | [ WARN:0@3.508] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (889) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
web_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
web_1       |     self.finish_response()
web_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 183, in finish_response
web_1       |     for data in self.result:
web_1       |   File "/code/users/views.py", line 81, in livefeed
web_1       |     jframe_bytes = camera_object.get_jpg_frame()
web_1       |   File "/code/users/views.py", line 75, in get_jpg_frame
web_1       |     retval, jframe = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
web_1       | cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:976: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !image.empty() in function 'imencode'
web_1       | 
web_1       | [04/Jan/2022 17:47:17] "GET /vidstream/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

I have tested this code on a Django project that is not deployed on Docker, and I get the video footage on the UI, so I know the issue lies within docker.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: You realize you try to access the webcam from the server right? Not the camera of the people that is *browsing* the page.

Comment: Hey @Willem Van Onsem - yes I am aware, this is how I want the application to run for the minute. FYI I am running on MacOS

Comment: so debug this. access the webcam through some other means, like ffmpeg. if that doesn't work either, at least the issue isn't unique to opencv.